# What is the ratio of the perimeter of $OPRQ$ to the perimeter of $OPSQ$?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

> Area of circle $O$ is $64\pi$. What is ratio of the perimeter of $OPRQ$ to that of $OPSQ$ ($\pi = 3$)?

Okay i have tried couple of things but seems its not working . Please suggest me proper solution of this example so that , i can solve similar questions.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by $\pi = 3$?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

arc length=$\dfrac {\theta}{360^\circ}\times2\pi r\;\;\;,$here $\theta\;$is angle made by arc on centre of circle.
$$m\widehat {PRQ}=\dfrac{120}{360}\times 2\pi\cdot8$$
$$m\widehat {PRQ}=\dfrac{16\pi}{3}$$
$$ m\widehat{PRQ}=16$$

$C=48\;,$$ m\widehat{PSQ}=C-m\widehat{PRQ}\implies48-16=32$

so ratio=$\dfrac {m\widehat{OPRQ}}{m\widehat{OPSQ}}=\dfrac{16}{32}\implies\dfrac 12$

Comment: No i am sorry . I think answer is wrong

Comment: we have options as follows : A) 2/3  B) 1/3 C) 1/2 D)3/4 E)2/5

Comment: ok I'm solving second arc

Answer (score 1):

Hint. From the area you are given ($64\pi = \pi r^2$), determine the radius, that gives you $OP$ and $OQ$.

To get the arc $PQ$, think what proportion of the circumference $C=2\pi r$) must be covered by $PQ$ if it corresponds to an angle of 120 degrees (how many degrees are in the entire circle?)

Comment: okay i have found the perimeter of circle which is 48 . How i can determine the PQ

Comment: @SSK The proportion of degrees must be the same as the proportion of the circumferences